# Flex 4 App Blank

Tags: apache-flex, maven, flex4, flexmojos

I'm building a Flex 4 app (using flexmojos rather than FlexBuilder). If I create a test Applications as follows, using mx:Application, then I see a button as I would expect:

```
<mx:Application
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <s:Button
        label="Button"/>

</mx:Application>
```

However, if I use s:Application then all I see is a blank (white) screen:

```
<s:Application
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">

    <s:Button
        label="Button"/>

</s:Application>
```

Incidentally I am not currently using an html wrapper, I'm just loading the swf directly in the browser.

Here is my pom...

```
<project 
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aaa.bbb</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2.0-SNAPSHOT-1</version>
    <name>app</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/flex</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <policyFileUrls>
                        <url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</url>
                    </policyFileUrls>
                    <rslUrls>
                        <url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/{extension}/flex/4.5.0.20967/{artifactId}_{version}.{extension}</url>
                    </rslUrls>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flex-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-swf</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <output>src/main/webapp/Main.swf</output>
                        </configuration>                        
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>textLayout</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>framework</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>sparkskins</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>rpc</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>datavisualization</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.17855</version>
          <type>swc</type>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
          <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.0.20967</version>
          <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

UPDATE:

I now have all the RLSs as .swz files stored in the same location as the .swf file, and I have the RSL URLs set as follows:

```
                            <configuration>
                    <policyFileUrls>
                        <url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/crossdomain.xml</url>
                    </policyFileUrls>
                    <rslUrls>
                        <url>{artifactId}_${flex.sdk.version}.{extension}</url>
                    <url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/{extension}/flex/${flex.sdk.version}/{artifactId}_${flex.sdk.version}.{extension}</url>
                    </rslUrls>
                </configuration>
```

Still, the app is just blank. Using FireBug there don't seem to be any requests for any RSLs that I can see, neither are there any error messages pertaining to this. It seems as though the RSL loading is not even attempted.

This is bizarre!

Comment: You should be getting an error.  Are you even running flash player debug?

Comment: Has there been any progress on this issue? I am facing the same issue, flex 4.5.1 release + flexmojos 3.8 (which I had to recompile with a newer flex-compiler-oem artifact)

Answer (score 5):

If you are on mojos < 4 add this to your configuration of your flexmojos-maven-plugin

```
<configuration>
    <configurationReport>true</configurationReport>
    <sourceFile>Main.mxml</sourceFile>
    <configFiles><!-- Fix for Mojos's < 4 -->
        <configFile>flex-config-swf-version-11.xml</configFile> 
    </configFiles> 
...
```

and then create this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<flex-config> 
        <swf-version>11</swf-version> 
</flex-config>
```

from: http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/browse_thread/thread/143f69219fcddc16#

if you are on 4+ you can add this to your configuration

```
<configuration>
    <configurationReport>true</configurationReport>
    <sourceFile>Main.mxml</sourceFile>
    <swfVersion>11</swfVersion>
...
```

from: http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/browse_thread/thread/9ff3ea2e0e0461a4

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem randomly when building with IntelliJ using ANT. Changing the targeted flash player version to 10.2, rather than 10.3 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue with Flex Mojos 4.0 and Flex 4.5. The problem got resolved when i upgraded to Flex Mojos 4.1-BETA.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is in RSLs which should be loaded by default but you haven't located them properly. Try to list all the required RSLs and change their scope to `merged`. I think [this](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/FAQ#FAQ-Q. HowdoIconfiguretheAdobesignedFlex4RSLdependencies?) and [this](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/FLEXMOJOS/Runtime+Shared+Libraries) links will be useful.

Comment: I think you are right about the RSLs, however I can't seem to get it to work. Your second link suggests using <scope>rsl<scope> or <scope>caching<scope>, yet neither of those are accepted by Maven which just says: must be one of [provided, compile, runtime, test, system] but is 'rsl'. Same goes for "merged". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It will be much more better if you post your POM.

Comment: Incidentally, I am running this within an execution block for a specific reason (even though that might not be the standard way)

Comment: Do you know what the URL for the RSLs is? I am behind a proxy, so maybe it is blocked, but I don't know what it is so I can't test that.

Comment: It seems as though the scope error message is a bit of a red herring ,just a warning from Maven, and in theory it should work. No joy though

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width to 100 and the height to 25 in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer, but more troubleshooting information that might help find the actual answer.  I am having the same outcome building the swf with make in IntellijIdea 10.  I am using the 4.5 SDK.

Somebody suggested that I needed flash player 11, which is in the incubator with Adobe.  I get the same results in flash player 11 (white screen when using spark, fine when using mx).

I use FlexMojos on other projects, but for this I am just doing some proof-of-concept testing with Flex 4.5 and did not want to introduce another variable to the build equation until I had things stabilized.

Hopefully this additional information will help you get to the bottom of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, for it to be used as rsl, u need to provide scope as caching
   `<scope>caching</scope>`. the warnings u get is just fine, and its a problem with flex-mojos and maven and i remember seeing it in a post in [flex-mojos-group](http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos). pls search for urself :)
2. check for the text layout version because it always comes with different number, than other
   framework rsls. i.e for text layout u need to have a seperate entry. refer [this](http://groups.google.com/group/flex-mojos/msg/c172556a230085dc)

   ```
               <rslUrls>
                   <url>{artifactId}_${flex.sdk.version}.{extension}</url>
                  <url>{artifactId}_${flex.textlayout.version}.{extension}</url><url>http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/{extension}/flex/${flex.sdk.version}/{artifactId}_${flex.sdk.version}.{extension}</url>
   ```
3. The number of entries in rslurls must match number of entries in policyurls tag.see [here](http://repository.sonatype.org/content/sites/flexmojos-site/4.0-SNAPSHOT/compile-swf-mojo.html#policyFileUrls). so policyFileUrls array of policy file URLs. Each entry in the rslUrls array must have a corresponding entry in this array
4. Use firefox's firebug extension, and observe the net console to see whether it's downloading rsls. U can also use [net-export](http://getfirebug.com/releases/extensions.html#netexport) plugin to save the netconsole logs and paste it.

modify your code to perform above checks and let know the results.